# Bluetooth Low Energy with IOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am experimenting with connecting to BLE devices on an iPhone and hope there maybe some experts out there who can help. I have been pretty successful at connecting to various devices but something is bugging me.

I have a Polar H7 Heart Rate Monitor - about as inductry standard as you can get.

I define

```
let BLE_Heart_Rate_Service_CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180D")
```

and use

```
self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLE_Heart_Rate_Service_CBUUID])
```

as predicted the central manager calls didDiscover and I can move on to connecting, discovering characteristices etc.

I also have a development board from Cypress which is programmed with Immediate Alert service (0x1802)

I define

```
let BLE_Find_Me_Service_CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x1802")
```

and call

```
self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLE_Find_Me_Service_CBUUID])
```

For this device it cannot find the device. didDiscover is not called

If I try

```
self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
```

I can debug print a list of every device found and the one I'm looking for is there.

I can filter in this call back on the name and move on but was wondering of anyone knew why scanForPeripherals works or doesnt work as I described.

Comment: When it appears in `didDiscover` read the advertisement data. I guess that it's not advertising that it has service "0x1802". So, since you filter `withService: [0x1802]`, it won't appear.

Comment: I have reviewed  the source code for the device and it does advertise.

Comment: And in your iPhone that's scanning, if you print the advertisement, does it appear?

Comment: The set of services that a device supports and the set that it advertises are different. Probably your device supports the immediate alert service but does not advertise it

Comment: Try using the nordic nRF Connect application to see your device, it will also show the services advertised

Comment: Very simple bcz BLE_Find_Me_Service_CBUUID is not found and when you set it nil It discovers all services.

Comment: So what was programmed into the Cypress dev board that was delivered was different to the code example. When I re-program with the code example the services are advertised. Thank you all for input.